# Порог для уровня вопросов снизу

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Встречаются вот такие [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889430/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-c):

> *как вызвать функцию? Можете прикрепить код?*

Это все. Мне кажется, что все же должен быть какой-то вменяемый нижний порог для уровня вопроса, иначе, как в анекдоте - до мышей... эволюционируем.

Может быть, ст*о*ит добавить еще и такой пункт в причины закрытия вопроса? (Коллегиальность не даст им злоупотреблять.) Согласитесь, что такие вопросы - это уже перебор. Или я чересчур строго подхожу к ситуации?

Comment: Щас_буит_мясо.jpg

Comment: Ещё как даст злоупотреблять.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы так говорите, будто это что-то плохое   (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно для этого заводить новую отдельную причину. Двух существующих причин для этого вполне достаточно, особенно первой:

1. > **Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.** Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, **что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.** Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.
2. > Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, **чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа**. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации.

*выделение болдом моё*

Comment: В вопросе из сабжа конкретная проблема - человек не знает, как вызвать функцию.

Comment: @Suvitruf прочитайте пожалуйста первую причину закрытия медленно, по частям ..

Comment: Прочитал, не понимаю. Ну ладно, видимо, я просто глупый.

Comment: Там обращение к ТС, с просьбой писать более развернутые вопросы .. какая ему ф-я нужна, для чего, и т.п. Просьба уточнить в чем у него проблема, что есть и что не получается. Просьба описать цель.

Comment: Ну, разве что... Ладно, останусь при своем мнении как при особом :)

Answer (score -2):

И как назвать эту причину? "Закрыть по причине того, что вопрос слишком глупый для SOru"?

Ну ладно, ладно. Мы же не хотим обижать пользователей. Тогда "Закрыть по причине того, что гуглится за пару секунд"? Не, в гугл тоже посылать нельзя.

Тогда "Закрыть по причине низкого качества"? Да вроде с качеством проблем нет.

Ещё хуже, если такие вопросы закрывать, то трафик же падать начнёт. Нельзя такое допускать.

Да и главная цель SO, цитирую, - **собрать в себе ответы на все возможные вопросы по программированию**.

Так что, нельзя такие вопросы трогать!

/irony

---

**TL;DR:** сжигать такие вопросы нужно, но текущая политика SE против этого. Так что, ничего не получится.

Единственное решение, которое мне видится, это причина закрытия с описанием того, что такие базовые вещи нужно изучать по учебнику.

Comment: Цель иронии не распознана. Нап**и**шете хотя бы TLDR общего посыла ответа?

Comment: @Kromster хм, хорошо, обновил ответ.

Comment: Оговорочка по Фрейду: вообще-то цель SO, цитирую - "собрать в себе ответы на все возможные вопросы по программированию". Updated: ну вот, поправили, а как шикарно звучало!

Comment: @AK ага, ниже в комментариях ниже выяснили, что я глупенький.