# Небольшое подведение итогов эксперимента по отключению причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки, цифры

Два месяца назад мы [отключили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9743/15479) причину закрытия вопросов «учебные задания». Попробуем разобраться, к чему это привело. Данные предоставил [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), за что ему спасибо.

Вопросы, заданные и закрытые в течение 7 дней с момента создания (по неделям):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Нет больших изменений в общем объёме закрытых вопросов.
2. Использование других похожих причин увеличилось, поскольку исчезла одна причина.

Посмотрим на другой график, который показывает эффективность первого голосования или тревоги на данном вопросе, по выбранной закрытой причине и неделе, когда он был поднят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Многие голоса за закрытие/тревоги не очень эффективны - они не приводят ни к закрытию вопроса, ни даже к рассмотрению на предмет закрытия.
2. Дубликаты, как и на многих сайтах, как правило, наиболее эффективны - есть участники с золотыми знаком по метке и тому подобное.
3. С "оффтопиком", как правило, всегда не густо - но нет заметных изменений во время этого теста.

Ещё две вещи:

1. Люди не вводили старую причину в поле при выборе "требуется вмешательство модератора". Самая распространённая причина в свободной форме (да и она нечасто использовалась):

   > данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)
2. Что случилось с тревогами или голосами с причиной, которую мы отключили? Было 65 вопросов с голосами/тревогами, ожидающими рассмотрения, на момент теста:

   ```
   Questions Flagged as 'Учебные задания допустимы...' Closed as...
   --------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
   55                                                  null
   5                                                   Needs details or clarity
   1                                                   Needs more focus
   4                                                   Off-topic
   ```

Большинство (84%) из них - вообще не были закрыты. В предыдущем месяце только 44% не были закрыты. Между тем, эффективность тревог/голосов с причиной в целом осталась примерно одинаковой.

Выводы Шога из всего вышесказанного:

1. Как и на многих сайтах, вопросов, нуждающихся в закрытии, больше, чем людей, которые могут их закрыть. Таким образом, любое изменение - даже полное устранение одной причины - вряд ли повлияет на общий объём закрытых вопросов; другие вопросы будут закрыты по другим причинам.
2. Не подтвердилось то, что вопросы, которые ранее закрывали как "домашки", теперь закрыты по другим причинам. Несомненно, некоторые вопросы были - как и в случае с 10 из 65, которые всё еще ожидали закрытия, когда начался тест, - но нет никаких доказательств того, что это было распространенным явлением. Впрочем, и нет свидетельств обратного.

Это хоть какая-то пища к размышлению. Теперь хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по этому поводу. Желательно, всё же, хоть с какой-то аргументацией.

Comment: Второй график странный: как будто длилось всё месяц, а не два. Ну и сам период эксперимента довольно необычный, выпадающий на НГ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вообще, хотели его до НГ провести. Но потом все по отпускам поуходили и данные смогли отсыпать только после НГ.

Comment: так в итоге, сколько длился эксперимент: месяц или два? Если два, то второй график странный. Если один, то начало поста странно звучит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ отключили 2 месяца назад. Эксперимент длился месяц. Потом месяц я ждал аналитику)

Comment: Нету метрик, о которых много говорили в предыдущей нити: количество минусов и, эм, неприятных комментариев на новых вопросах, а также участников, у которых эти минусы и комментарии отбили желание участвовать.

Кроме того, интересно было бы увидеть результаты по «домашкиным» меткам, таким как [pascal], [java], и [c].

Comment: @Ainar-G по комментариям запрос вряд ли получится составить. Такое только если эмпирически оценивать.

Comment: Я не пойму, а чего вообще ожидали? Или причина закрытия теперь выбирается едва ли не наобум (типа "непонятный вопрос", где все кристалльно ясно), либо просто - а, нет - ну и хрен с ним...

Comment: @Harry вроде как ожидалось, что не будут закрывать, а будут минусовать и удалять.

Comment: @Harry лично я ожидал, что не будут убиваться неплохие вопросы. Но что это, что анализ комментариев - это чисто эмпирические показатели =/

Comment: **Неплохие** учебные вопросы - там, где вопрос был интересен, заставлял думать и т.д. - не убивали и раньше. Imho. Я даже, бывало, минусы на них зарабатывал :), отвечая - когда вопрос не просто "напишите за меня умножение двух чисел", а с тонкостью, которая, может, и не подразумевалась преподом :) Я уже писал, что скорее имеет смысл заменить эту причину на причину (как ее оформить - дело другое) "слишком тупой вопрос". Остаюсь при своем мнении :)

Comment: Видимо я слишком плох в анализе данных, но в приведенных графиках я не вижу ничего информативного

Comment: @Harry тоже вариант. Опубликуйте ответом. Этот вопрос как раз в целях обсуждения создан.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica См. [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8076/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83) и [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9774/195342)

Comment: @Harry этот пост как подведение итогов, хотелось бы всё в одном месте иметь.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Считайте, что я с придыханием, как Калугина в "Служебном романе" - "я вам не верю..." :) Простите, но я вообще не люблю на мете бывать и что-то тут писать. Тем более там, где, *как я считаю*, все предрешено заранее. Эксперимент проводился (**imho**) только для того, чтоб не дать повода для возмущения "почему убрали?!", а убрать причину мягко - так сказать, сварить лягушку медленно. Убрали, как способ повысить количество вопросов, чтоб статистика выглядела красивее (как версия? :)). Вобщем, мое предложение все равно не пройдет, все решено - не буду и стараться..

Comment: @Harry почему не пройдёт? Мне идея с введением причины с другим описанием в принципе нравится. И я бы не стал её так сразу отметать.

Comment: @yolosora это типичная проблема подобных инициатив. Статистически сложно оценить, тем более у нас, т.к. участников мало. На enSO, всё же, с этим получше. Такое только если эмпирически оценивать. Но у меня из-за модерации и так времени особо не остаётся )=

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ее отметаю (отмету?) не я...

Comment: Что делаем дальше? Оставляем причину или нет? (Может проголосовать?)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пока ждём других мнений. Потом отдельный вопрос с голосованием сделаем, если понадобится.

Comment: Голосование нужно было до эксперимента, чтобы узнать отношение сообщества к нему. Фактически, это как показ графиков лабораторным мышам (для создания некой иллюзии контакта и взаимодействия). По сути же, если голосования не было - весь эксперимент это просто мракобесие отдельной группы лиц, и непонятно чьи интересы он представляет, имхо.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Шога выперли. Что думаете по данному поводу?

Comment: @Zhigalin как это к вопросу относится? Да, статистику больше не у кого брать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да никак если честно, просто хотелось услышать ваши мысли, тем более что вы модератор с говорящим ником.

Comment: @Zhigalin увольнение осуждаю, если вам интересно.

Comment: Что дальше? Кажется все желающие высказались.

Comment: Два месяца шёл эксперимент (из которых месяц - за счёт ожидания статистики). Ок, результаты есть. По ним все желающие высказались (в течение последней недели не добавилось ни одного сообщения или комментария по  сути вопроса). И теперь хочется узнать - а результат-то будет? Какое будет принято решение - не спрашиваю, но результат хоть какой-нибудь? с учётом того, что найти высказывающегося явно за сохранение текущего, без временно удалённой причины, состояния, я что-то не вижу... или острота снята, пар спущен, и достаточно? Ну так хотя бы скажите явно "Останется так, как сейчас"...

Answer (score 26):

Я считаю, стоит вернуть причину на место.

Когда эту причину закрытия отключали, привели [следующие аргументы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/):

> 1. Закрываются хорошие вопросы. Если вопрос является "домашкой" - это ещё не означает, что вопрос плох. Он всё ещё может быть полезен
>      сообществу.
> 2. Закрытие с этой причиной некоторых авторов сбивает с толку.
> 3. Такие вопросы после закрытия попадают в очередь, где требуется участие 5 человек для решения дальнейшей судьбы вопроса

По порядку:

---

> *"1. Закрываются хорошие вопросы. Если вопрос является "домашкой" - это ещё не означает, что вопрос плох. Он всё ещё может быть полезен сообществу." — [(c)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/)*

Раз количетсво закрытых вопросов не изменилось, значит в этом плане отключение причины не ничего не дало:

> Нет больших изменений в общем объёме закрытых вопросов.

> Использование других похожих причин увеличилось, поскольку исчезла одна причина.

Почему-то ниже написали, что

> Не подтвердилось то, что вопросы, которые ранее закрывали как "домашки", теперь закрыты по другим причинам. ... Впрочем, и нет свидетельств обратного.

Но я с этим совершенно не согласен. Как же "не подтвердилось", если количество закрытых вопросов не изменилось? Другие причины стали использовать больше.

Примеры домашки, закрытой с неправильной причиной:
**[1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068617)
[2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069129)
[3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068278)
[4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067887)
[5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067900)
[6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068897)
[7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067463)
[8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067332)
[9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066186)** - Думаю этого достаточно? Это только за последние 10 дней, только по тегу C++.

Кроме того, я не видел, чтобы этой причиной злоупотребляли. Есть примеры таких незаслуженно закрытых вопросов?

---

> *"2. Закрытие с этой причиной некоторых авторов сбивает с толку." — [(c)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/)*

Не понял, при чем тут это. Если текст причины закрытия сбивает с толку (в чем я сомневаюсь, ни разу такого не видел), то нужно исправлять текст причины, а не убирать ее.

Мне кажется, закрытие вопросов про домашку с неправильными причинами, вызванное этим экспериментом, гораздо больше сбивает с толку.

Вот например: [вопрос с домашкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069129) закрыли с неправильной причиной: *"Этот вопрос необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями."*

Если бы я был автором этого вопроса, мне было бы совершенно непонятно, чего от меня хочет сообщество. "дополнить подробностями" - куда уж подробнее, если в вопросе задание приведено дословно? Еще и заминусили, не объяснив за что. А потом мы удивляемся, что SO критикуют за токсичность.

С другой стороны, в старой причине было понятным языком написано, что мы хотим от автора вопроса:

> **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Это объясняет автору, что ему нужно делать, чтобы его вопросы не закрывали, и объясняет ему причину минсов.

---

> *"3. Такие вопросы после закрытия попадают в очередь, где требуется участие 5 человек для решения дальнейшей судьбы вопроса" — [(c)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/)*

Раз количество закрываемых вопросов не изменилось, то в этом плане отключение причины ничего не дало.

---

И еще одна причина, почему стоит верунть все как было:

У меня нет доказательств, но мне кажется, что теперь вопросы с домашкой стали закрывать медленее - кто-то стесняется использовать "неправильную" причину закрытия.

<sup>(@Shog9 этого не измерил, но теперь его уже не спросить. Он [покинул славные ряды](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9) сотрудников SE.)</sup>

Это плохо, потому что у людей с приступами альтруизма появляется больше времени, чтобы отвечать на такие вопросы. А если на них будут отвечать, то их авторы будут снова и снова возвращаться к нам со своей домашкой (может быть даже порекомендуют SO друзьям-халявщикам), и качество вопросов на SO будет ухудшаться.

Причина популярности SO (в первую очередь английского SO) - качество накопленного там контента. Он не забит мусорными вопросами.

Comment: "Он не забит мусорными вопросами" забит.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ну, это субъективно. :) Да и смотря с чем сранивать. Открыл вкладку Active по тегу С++ на английском SO - на первой странице один вопрос с домашкой без попытки решения. Открыл то же самое у нас - 3 вопроса.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А что думаете по поводу остальных пунктов?

Comment: _Как же "не подтвердилось", если количество закрытых вопросов не изменилось?_  Подтвердилось бы если бы очередь вопросов на закрытие разгребалась бы под 0, просто при обработке очередей, вероятно, обработали больше вопросов с другими причинами закрытия

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сложно всё. Но, как минимум, мне бы вот так сразу возвращать причину не хотелось бы, вспоминая, сколько месяцев мы пытались её убрать. И аналитику хз откуда брать, учитывая, что Шога выгнали. Такую аналитику всегда только он предоставлял )=

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica [Sunk cost fallacy](https://www.behavioraleconomics.com/resources/mini-encyclopedia-of-be/sunk-cost-fallacy/). :P

Comment: Большое спасибо! Отличный ответ. Полностью согласен.

Answer (score 25):

Само собой, мое чисто субъективное мнение.

Результатом эксперимента стало закрытие вопросов с едва ли не первой попавшейся под мышку причиной. Потому что писать свой текст в "Другое" не у каждого хватает терпения.

Количество ответов на такие вопросы немного увеличилось - что в результате не дает потом никаких оснований для чистки: есть вопрос, есть принятый ответ - что еще нужно?

Меня лично эти вопросы беспокоят не как вопросы от лентяев сами по себе - они связаны с резким снижением уровня ruSO. Когда человек приходит с вопросом "как вызвать функцию?" - это уже предельная лень и нежелание учиться. Задекларированной **пользы для сообщества** от такого вопроса - ноль.

Поэтому я бы скорее вернул причину не только "учебные задания", но и добавил бы

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, опечаткой или незнанием азов.

С рекомендацией сообществу - не давать ответ, но в комментариях подтолкнуть в нужную сторону (комментария обычно достаточно, чтобы ответить на такой вопрос). Так что такие вопросы благополучно закрывались бы, при этом вопрошающий получал бы толчок (зачастую большой шаг вперед является результатом хорошего пинка в зад) в нужном направлении, и не терял бы возможность добиться чего-то своим трудом и получить удовольствие от самостоятельного понимания :)

Но, вообще говоря, что-то мне слабо верится, что наши доводы - а их в пользу возврата, как мне кажется, больше, чем против - к чему-то приведут :(

Comment: +1, в "ленте" стало больше бесполезных (полезных только авторам) вопросов о проблемах вызванных незнанием основ. И хотя в справке написано _«Вопросы должны быть узкими — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.»_, парадоксально что такие вопросы находят поддержку участников и модераторов (что вскрывает гораздо более серьезную проблему, чем толком не обоснованное удаление причины закрытия. Очевидно, ruSO сейчас переживает трудный период).

Comment: Незнание азов не должно закрываться. Это уже обсуждали.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы так пишете, как будто если вопрос обсужден - то больше к нему возвращаться нельзя. А по делу - ruSO такими вопросами все больше превращается из ruSO в какую-то, не хотелось бы говорить это слово, неструктурированную помойку. Просто форум без права личной переписки, не более того. Это уже не тот сайт, каким я увидел его 4 года назад, когда еще хоть как-то, но можно было выполнять ПОИСК. Сейчас множество вопросов - с одним тегом языка (часто неверного), заголовком "Чё за хня?" и описанием "компилятор лагает" + (если повезет) код без пояснения, что он должен делать. Утрирую? увы...

Comment: 1. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988. 2. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988. А то, что ты описываешь, как раз к азам никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Про вызов функции есть интересное наблюдение — на мой взгляд, такие вопросы очень нужны, особенно для тех, кто хочет сделать что–то быстро не осваивая инструмент «от и до» (например, иногда, для меня =). Я уйму раз находил полезные ответы на до стыда банальные вопросы ([например](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10341032/564240) или [другой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3846935/564240)). С текущей скоростью развития технологий все запомнить невозможно, но попробовать технологии хочется =)

Answer (score 24):

Если честно, не очень понятно, что эксперимент и эти данные должны были показать. Эксперимент не имеет смысла без гипотезы. Когда предлагали убрать причину, никто не привел серьезных доказательств того, что ей часто злоупотребляют. Кроме того, это предложение, на первый взгляд, было обосновано ошибочными предпосылками о том, что "домашку можно просто удалять, а не закрывать", хотя на самом деле это не работает.

Единственное, что мне видно из графиков - что теперь доминирует причина "Непонятна суть вопроса". Что ожидаемо - большая часть домашки, которую закрывали предыдущей причиной, формулируется как "напишите ...", "нужно сделать ..." без конкретного вопроса, и попадает под эту причину (см. например [pascal Напишите программу подсчета количества элементов этого массива, имеющих максимальное значение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068957/)).

Мне кажется, наличие причины закрытия это не та вещь которую можно решить анализом статистики, это вопрос стандарта качества. Или мы решаем, что домашка без попыток решения (не важно, как сформулировано) недопустима, и тогда причина нужна. Или мы убираем причину, и тогда мы устанавливаем более низкий стандарт. Эксперимент тут ничего не покажет.

Answer (score 22):

Я скорее делюсь наблюдением, но вопросы по тегу `pascal`,
например, стали получать намного больше минусов и грубости.  Если до
отключения причины я редко видел `-4`, то теперь каждый день
можно наблюдать `-6`–`-7` и множество
*«юмористических»* комментариев.

Я с самого начала был против отключения причины, и мое мнение остаётся
прежним.  В определённых тегах есть проблема с лентяями и домашкой.
Причина закрытия нужна.

Comment: Подаёте это так, будто люди стали злыми из-за того, что убрали причину (: Если люди грубят и юморят, то нужно флагать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica  А я флагаю.  И местами флаги отклоняют.  Портить свою статистику по флагам тоже особо не хочется.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica _«Подаёте это так, будто люди стали злыми из-за того, что убрали причину»_ - да неужели

Comment: @Ainar-G [Верхние три вопроса на сегодня](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx7VP.png) ;)

Answer (score 12):

Я считаю, что надо вернуть причину. Домашки закрывают все равно. Даже если их не закрывать, их по любому заминусуют и  Дух Сообщества их удалит. У сообщества уже устоялись взгляды, что делать с учебными заданиями и даже если отдельные участники против закрытия (avp), то в целом мнение не поменялось.

Причину также стоит вернуть из-за того, что это лучше, чем использовать неподходящую (хотя я так делаю).

В общем: *I say Reinstate Homework Flag too*

**P.S** Хочу поблагодарить модератора @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica за статистику, которую многие не оценили, мне она была  интересна и полезна.

Answer (score 4):

> Использование других похожих причин увеличилось, поскольку исчезла
>   одна причина.

Это естественно. Так делали и раньше, когда не было отдельной причины для закрытия "домашек" (буду использовать сложившийся в сообществе термин). Разве, что сейчас стали меньше голосовать за закрытие и больше минусовать.

А, так. Мнение сообщества в отношении подобных вопросов уже давно сформировалось и не понятно чего добиваются инициаторы этого эксперимента.

С одной стороны такие вопросы, это то же контент. Но, какова ценность контента, который, образно говоря, написан на первых страницах учебника?

Главная ценность SO, ИМХО, в том, что здесь можно получить ответ на вопросы, на которые нигде (или почти нигде) больше не ответят. На вопросы, которые слабо или вовсе не отражены в различной литературе и документации. На вопросы, с которыми может помочь только человек с соответствующим опытом.

Такие вопросы, на которые есть ответы приводят из поисковиков очень много людей, которые потом становятся постоянной аудиторией сайта. Но, самое главное, что "домашки" создают трудности даже для них. В некоторых сообществах нормальный вопрос просто "тонет" среди потока очередных "Спасите! Помогите! Сортировка "пузырьком"! Помогите с Pascal! Нужно срочно!" и т.п. Как следствие уменьшается вероятность получить ответ на него. Что соответствующим образом влияет на уровень и ценность этого сообщества.

На ruSO к счастью такого пока не наблюдается, хотя предпосылки уже есть.

В целом своё мнение относительно отключения отдельной причины закрытия для "домашек" я уже озвучивал ранее [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/9757#9757) и оно не изменилось.