# Что будем делать с причиной закрытия "учебные задания"?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

Полмесяца назад опубликовали [итоги](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10013/) эксперимента по отключению причины.

> Пока ждём других мнений. Потом отдельный вопрос с голосованием сделаем, если понадобится
>   *— [Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica ♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10013/10016#comment41841_10013) 15 янв в 19:56*

Похоже все желающие отписались, последний ответ под тем вопросом был 10 дней назад.

Думаю пора решать, что делать. Возвращаем причину? Или [объединяем с другой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10036/215103)?

Comment: Нет, так объединять мы точно не будем. И возвращать - тоже. Если уж надо, то будем формулировать заново.

Comment: @Qwertiy А почему не будем возвращать? Судя по ответам и комментам под тем постом, много кто за возврат.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat они не за возврат, они не хотят видеть "домашки". Нужно отталкиваться от изначальной проблемы. Проблему с домашками можно решать по-другому.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica 3 из 5 ответов прямым текстом предлагают вернуть причину. *"Нужно отталкиваться от изначальной проблемы."* Я, честно говоря, так и не понял, какая была проблема. По-моему, все работало нормально. :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat потому что они даже не рассматривали другие возможные пути решения.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Например какие? Другая формулировка?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat одна из проблем в том, что закрывалось много неплохих вопросов с этой причиной.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Слышал этот аргумент, но некорректно закрытых вопросов не видел (вообще ни одного). Можете показать парочку таких?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Квертий и Паша много примеров приводили в старых обсуждениях.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Пошел листать...

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Не могу найти. Нашел [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6189/), но здесь старая формулировка причины. Ее с тех пор поменяли, как раз чтобы не злоупотребляли.

Comment: @Qwertiy тебе проще будет найти, подкинешь ссылок? )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, неа. Но я могу подкинуть вот это: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988 & https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988 - во втором есть альтернативная формулировка, которую ещё не пробовали.

Comment: @Qwertiy Идея из второго вопроса мне нравится, только я бы переформулировал более простым языком (думаю большинство студентов, которые приходят сюда с домашкой, не знают слова "атомарный").

Comment: Но с другой стороны, если существующей причиной не злоупотребляли, нужно ли вообще ее менять?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica ^

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, главное чтобы те, кто закрывает знали ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Не согласен, но это можно обсудить, если мы решим ввести эту причину. :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Все-таки я так и не понял, чем плоха предыдущая причина.

Comment: Я за добавление причины закрытия "Учебные задания" и категорически против добавления метки на **SO ru**. Вторая ссылка Qwertiy полностью отображает моё мнение на это счёт. Если человек хотя бы как-то попытался решить задачу и выкладывает свои попытки - это так и так подходит под вопросы текущих меток помощи с кодом. А если это просто желание, чтобы за тебя решили задачу, да ещё и с картинками, вместо вопроса - это уже край. Это просто превратит портал в `готовые ответы`, как раньше в школе по учебникам. Зачем решать задачи за других?

Comment: Это изначально противоречит как моральной так и этической части вопроса. Задачи не просто так придумывают и создают. Это тоже требует определённых усилий. Сама суть задач - научить людей решать подобные задачи, а не уметь находить на них готовый ответ в интернете. Всё это приведёт к тому, что **SO** превратится в портал решения задач на заказ. Большинство вопросов с учебными заданиями оформляют те, кому категорически лень думать самостоятельно. Они даже оформляют их соответствующе(тупо картинки), даже не желая переписать вопрос.Какая цена репутации человека, который решает УЧЕБНЫЕ задачи?Фу-фу

Comment: @Denis640Kb думаю, достаточно не закрывать те задачи, которые пытались решить. Если что-то конкретное не получается - всегда можно указать на такой момент. А всю задачу решать за человека - медвежья услуга, я считаю. Да и мало кому решение пользу принесет. На счет полезных "домашек" хорошо сказал Victor says Reinstate Monica в комментарии к ответу nomnoms12. И действительно - приведенные в пример вопросы были очень конкретны.

Comment: Пора сделать голосовалку и повесить ее на главную страницу -)

Comment: @avp Я только за.

Answer (score 22):

Тут в комментариях под вопросом прозвучало

> одна из проблем в том, что закрывалось много неплохих вопросов с этой причиной

Ерунда. Ну будут вопросы закрываться с другими причинами, только и всего.

Вы хотите увеличить статистику вопросов? Просто запретите закрывать вопросы вообще.

И еще - зачем эти игры в демократию? Обсуждения, после которых, несмотря на мнение пользователей, раздается "*нет, так поступать мы точно не будем*". По мне - или объявляйте формальное голосование **и подчиняйтесь его решениям**, или скажите прямо - мол, у нас тут *суверенная демократия*, и все будет ясно-понятно...

Все эти эксперименты с обсуждениями, которые пошли не так, как хотелось их инициаторам, с оттягиванием решения "а, поговорят и забудут" - оско... вызывают отрицательные чувства куда больше, чем отсутствие того или иного пункта для причины закрытия...

Comment: "Ерунда" Вот вот. Примеры таких вопросов я так и не увидел. "игры в демократию" У меня такое ощущение, что кому-то из модераторов понравилась эта идея, и он убедил остальных и протащил ее. А заморачиваться с оценкой результата такого изменения или придумывать другую причину на замену - у них большого желания нет.

Comment: Ни добавить, ни прибавить, что называется)

Comment: Зачем возвращаться на шаг назад, если можно сделать шаг вперёд?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вообще-то был сделан шаг *назад*. Теперь вместо того, чтоб хотя бы вернуться, нас кормят какими-то обещаниями "вот Чапай подумает, Чапай решит".

Comment: [Попробовали проголосовать...](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10084) 

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Третий вариант настолько странный, что...

Comment: @Qwertiy Какой шаг вперёд?

Comment: *одна из проблем в том, что закрывалось много неплохих вопросов с этой причиной* Категорически против использования в этой фразе слова "много". Это как с фразой "Всем известно, что..." - и даже спорить бессмысленно. Да, есть.. но соотношение вопросов, действительно заслуживающих жить, пусть они и явная домашка, и вопросов, которым место на помойке - весьма высокое (во всяком случае для тех тегов, которые лично мне интересны). В связи с чем комментарии с такими фразами лично для меня больше смахивают не то на демагогию, не то на сознательное (а, может, и бессознательное) передёргивание фактов.

Comment: Честно говоря, мне ни холодно, ни жарко от наличия или отсутствия причины. Меня больше беспокоит то, что сообщество игнорируют. Я понимаю, что демократия тут осталась только в постах "дедов", но зачем в очередной раз это показывать - я не знаю. В данном вопросе нет никакой принципиальности. бОльшая часть сообщества выразила свою точку зрения. Почему нельзя вернуть, а вот потом, когда "подумОют" предложить другой вариант? Мой вариант "и волки сыты, и овцы целы" - разрешить правильно оформленные учебные вопросы с попыткой решения, остальные - в печь.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте просто ставить метку на такие вопросы. Кому не интересно поставят метку в игнор, но и найдутся те, кто захочет отслеживать такие вопросы.

Предлагаю сделать причину закрытия "текст картинкой". Вопрос должен гуглиться иначе он бесполезен для сообщества. Львиная доля домашек плохого качества - это картинки с учебника.

Остальные можно минусовать и плюсовать.

Comment: Почему вы всё в одну кучу складываете? Текст картинкой - это не про домашки, это просто плохо оформленный вопрос.

Comment: Большая часть домашек это текст картинкой. И закрывать их надо по причине текст картинкой. Остальные домашки пусть живут - они полезны для других учеников

Comment: Я не против закрытия, если что. Я лишь к тому, что не важно, домашка или нет. Это просто плохо оформленный вопрос.

Comment: Причину для текста картинкой уже есть - _(Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.)_ Нужно просто в тексте причины особо упомянуть и про текст картинкой.

Comment: Вот её и используем. Остальную домашку можно минусить и плюсовать. Хорошие вопросы остаются - плохие вылезут в "похожих" и остановят кого-то от набора дубля

Comment: Я бы сделал отдельную причину для картинок. С ними надо бороться отдельно

Comment: Очень хорошая идея, сделать специальную метку "Домашнее задание"/"homework" и проставлять её таким вопросам... Не отвергайте эту мысль, на мой взгляд это оптимальное решение...

Comment: @eri у нас довольно много таких вопросов с картинками. Оформите отдельным обсуждением на добавление причины закрытия для этого. Не думаю, что кто-то против будет ^_^

Comment: @eri Ну и всегда, для таких постов, с картинками, можно всегда попросить правильно оформить вопрос. Если меня просят поправить вопрос(чаще ответ) я всегда реагирую. Если нет реакции, тогда, да. Закрывать.

Comment: Поисковым системам метки безразличны, поэтому выдача гугля может быть зашумлена домашками лентяев..

Comment: что нужно гуглить чтоб нагуглить домашку, даже без учета метки? правильно - такую же домашку.

Answer (score 3):

Как по мне, вопросы с учебным заданием сами по себе ничего плохого не несут. Основная проблема заключается в том, что многие авторы просто пишут текст (и это в лучшем случае, иногда — просто картинку) задания и ждут, пока это задания за них сделают. Так что проблема именно в этом — **автор ждет, что за него сделают его работу**.

Предлагаю создать новую причину закрытия — «работа за автора». Содержание можно сделать примерно таким:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как предполагает выполнение работы за автора. На данном ресурсе лишь *помогают* решить проблему, а не делают все за вас. Для получения ответа приведите свои собственные наработки и попытки решения, а также сформулируйте *конкретную проблему*, вызывающую затруднение.

Comment: Получается вопросы [типа такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) тоже будут запрещены, если автор не погуглил?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну почему. Здесь автор задал конкретный вопрос. Тем более он [вопрос] довольно каноничен. К тому же, StackExchange позиционирует себя  как база вопросов и ответов для программистов. Вопрос по ссылке оказался полезен ~3кк человек, вопрос же типа «написать калькулятор на ц++» окажется полезен только одному человеку — самому ТС.

Comment: Я не спорю, что вопрос хороший, но мне кажется, что на него можно натянуть такую причину закрытия, потому что в вопросе не показаны попытки разобраться самостоятельно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, но ведь никакой *работы* за автора не предполагается.  Автор, наоборот, сам стремится разобраться в разнице между `git pull` и `get fetch`. А делится знаниями в разнице между этими командами — не работа за автора. Не каждый умеет результативно гуглить, да и зачастую информацию в документации не так просто найти.

Comment: Тут надо понимать, что в причине закрытия фигурировало "учебные задания" только потому, что это наиболее распространенный тип мусора на сайте. Если кто-то, например, свои задачи с работы скидывает как есть на SO и просит решить, это так же плохо, как и домашка. Но такого обычно не бывает, потому что это нереалистично. Чтобы решить за кого-то задачу на работе, понадобится с месяц только входить в курс дела. Поэтому расширять причину бессмысленно - мы просто не сталкиваемся достаточно часто с "неучебными заданиями".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, когда в причине закрытия фигурирует «учебные задания» складывается ощущение, что SO неприемлет учебные задания вообще. Название «работа за автора» более релевантно, ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная идее eri идея. Можно было бы сделать нечто вроде вкладки "учебные задания" (там же где"новые", "текущие".и т.д.) и перемещать туда домашки, а из других удалять. Тогда бы, кто хотел, отвечал. А остальныx бы они не бесили.Проблема в том, что это можно сделать только изменяя движок, а идти на MSE с этой идеей  я категорически не хочу.

По поводу идеи eri: метка для этого не предназначена, хотя вообще мне его мысль понравилась.

**Вывод** (не stdout, а *вывод* ;)): Вернуть причину и дело с концом.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Вот например мое мнение.

Comment: Я за отдельную метку, благо фильтрация есть, отчего-б её не использовать по прямому назначению?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю **сделать метку** [учебные-задания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Причину *"учебные задания"* **не возвращать**, новые не добавлять.

---

Вопросы, связанные с выполнением учебных заданий, IMHO, очень хорошо вписываются в тематику нашего сайта на данный момент.

Часто на них можно увидеть эталонные ответы, в которых подробно разобрано применения какого-либо математического метода/алгоритма. Очень интересно посмотреть на такие решения, сравнить их и обсудить с коллегами. Очень часто я нахожу в них новую, полезную для себя информацию, которая очень помогает мне. Лично я хотел бы видеть такие вопросы/ответы.

*Примеры:*

- [Генерация случайного числа по заданному распределению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1054252/339283) (+8 | +11 | конкурс на 50)
- [Найти число, которое является некоторой степенью двойки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1053498/339283) (+7 | +8/+6/+6/+5)

Но есть группа людей, которые их видеть не хотели бы. В таком случае, исходя из возможностей движка, игнорирование метки удовлетворит их потребность. А то, что метка не отражает конкретную технологию, совсем не проблема. У нас уже есть подобные метки:

- [код-гольф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84)
- [поиск-библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba)
- [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc)

---

Причину *"учебные задания"* возвращать не стоит. Если задание учебное, это ещё не значит, что оно плохое. Этим всё сказано.

Проблемы с форматированием большинства подобных вопросов к причине *"учебные задания"* отношения не имеют. Для плохо оформленных вопросов существует причина *"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой..."*, которую и **стоит уточнять**, чтобы исключить недопонимание. Считаю, что в неё явно нужно **добавить пункт**, говорящий, что прикладывать код изображением нельзя.

Comment: А что будем тогда делать с тем, что большинство участников минусуют эти вопросы, а Дух Сообщества их удаляет? Вы предлагаете легализовать "учебные задания". Легализовать то их может и легализуют, но отношение соответственное к ним все равно останется. По поводу поиска библиотек: обеими руками за. Мне такие вопросы часто помогают, жалко если их закрывают.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica _"большинство минусуют эти вопросы"_, — нет, это не так. Я специально привёл примеры. Возьмём [первый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1054252/339283). На нём +8/0, и это при том, что в нём нет ни строчки кода, как и мыслей автора. Но вопрос великолепен! Это я всё к тому, что плохие вопросы всегда будут минусовать, а хорошие — плюсовать. Мы же сейчас обсуждаем в целом **тематичность** таких вопросов. Я считаю, что им место на сайте.

Comment: Среди плюсов вопроса из примера один мой. Но это не учебное задание, это атомарной вопрос.

Comment: синоним домашнее-задание поставьте ещё

Comment: Угу, а лучше вообще отключить все причины для закрытия и создать метку "помойка" - вдруг найдутся желающие поотвечать

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Не вопрос хорош, а ответ...

Answer (score -3):

Очевидно, что раз причина использовалась на вопросах, которые закрывать не стоило, возвращать её в той же формулировке абсолютно бессмысленно. Надо подобрать для неё другую, более точную формулировку, чтобы исключить её необоснованное использование.

В одном их прошлых [обсуждений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988) я уе предлагал возможный вариант:

> Вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий, например, математику и ввод-вывод. Возможно его стоит разбить на соответствующие атомарные вопросы, но предварительно стоит убедиться, что такие вопросы ещё не задавались, потому что в большинстве случаев вероятность существования таких вопросов достаточно велика.

Этот вариант основан на [соответствующем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988) с рейтингом +23 -2 и призван выделить следующие моменты:

- Большинство домашек из серии "сделай за меня задание целиком" ей неявно покрывается. Никто не задаёт написать функцию поиска минимума в массиве, задуют написать порграмму с заполнением массиваи его обработкой. Если учащийся ничего не дела скопипастил задание, то оно этой причиной почти наверняка покрывается.
- А если всё-таки сделал, и задал вопрос _"как найти минимум в массиве", то это хороший вопрос. Вопросы по азам - это нормально. Их не надо ни закрывать (кроме дубликатов, конечно), ни минусовать.

Comment: *"раз причина использовалась на вопросах, которые закрывать не стоило"* Можете привести примеры таких вопросов?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не складывал себе никуда их список. Но многие помнят, что они были. Даже по темам, на которые я уже дал ссылки, видно, что пытались закрывать лишнее.

Comment: Наоборот, Паша пишет, что [*"Сейчас ей вроде бы не злоупотребляют."* (15 окт '19)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9632/215103). Все упоминания о злоупотреблениях, которые я нашел, относятся к старой формулировке (до 2017), которую изменили специально чтобы это исправить.

Comment: Сама идея выглядит неплохо, но я считаю, что не стоит чинить то, что не сломано.

Comment: А может пора прислушаться к мнению сообщества и вернуть как было?

Comment: @edem, и нет такого мнения.

Comment: Можно посчитать голоса на ответах здесь, например.

Comment: @edem Нет такого общего мнения: nomnoms12 хочет ввести метку, avp хочет оставить эти вопросы вообще и т.д.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Конечно часть людей против, но у меня тоже ощущение, что большинство за то, чтобы вернуть как было. По хорошему, можно сделать голосование...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Давайте зададим вопрос-голосование и дадим в нем два варианта ответа (общих, за которые будут голосовать): "Вернуть причину" и "Не вернуть причину".

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Угу, сделаете?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10084/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/10086#10086