# Предлагаю голосовать за возвращение причины учебные задания

Tags: обсуждение, голосование, домашки

Желающие ставят плюс одному из ответов ниже.

Голосовать против нельзя, а то будет неудобно подсчитывать голоса (будем считать только плюсы, минусы игнорируем).

Также можете аргументировать свою позицию в комментариях к ответам.

Comment: Не уверен, что им уведомления приходят. Надежнее кастомный флаг.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Флаг поставил тоже — с самого начала. Но на мете тревоги обрабатывают медленно, я думал лучше так.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почему голосовать против нельзя? И не надо удалять обоснование из ответов. лучше б наоборот ещё дописал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не добавлял это требование, оно было в вопросе изначально.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обоснования убрал, потому что мы эти аргументы уже до дыр замусолили. Лучше добавить ссылки на существующие обсуждения.

Comment: Убираю [meta-tag:важное], пока не разберёмся с формулировкой ответов.

Comment: Чтоб проводить такие голосования, нужно в вопросе раскрыть проблему, описать как следует. В ответах привести все за и против. Это не та вещь, для которой простых "Да/нет" хватит. Такие решения нужно принимать обдумано.

Comment: Тема важная для сообщества, я предлагаю подготовить её как следует, а потом уже выносить на общее обсуждение. Сам я пока плотно занят, но рассчитываю обязательно присоединиться на выходных. Я бы вообще предложил вот что. У нас на мете есть как некоторое пассивное большинство (кто охотно поддерживает голосование, ставя апвоут/даунвоут, реже -- комментируя и тем более не оставляя ответы), думаю они готовы высказаться по поводу причины домашки в голосовании, есть те, кто весьма активно принимает участие в этом вопросе. Может нам как-то попробовать собрать активистов, чтобы проработать вопрос?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica молодец, поддерживаю возвращение причины закрытия.

Comment: @AK согласен, можно попробовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Давайте навесим вопросу метку [важное].

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Давайте навесим вопросу метку [важное]

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica в понедельник будет вопрос с описание всей этой ситуации, на нём будет [meta-tag:важное].

Answer (score 13):

## Да, вернуть причину.

Старый вариант:

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

или любые другие, но соответствующие тому, что домашки надо закрывать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, добавь аргументы прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy По ссылке, которую я оставил, три ответа с аргументами за. Переписывать - много.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не согласен.

Comment: Позвал в модераторском чате SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica и AK сюда.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, такой ответ бесполезен.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Я бы не стал дописывать "или любые другие" ПОСЛЕ того, как кто-то проголосовал. Уж или верните оригинальный вариант, или оставьте как есть.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat для подобных вопросов нужна полноценная аргументация в самих ответах. Как минимум, чтобы люди не в теме, могли понять суть ответа.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вообще-то голоса были до того, как я дописал, что вернуть надо в старой формулировке...

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вот, как видите, мнение большинства "За".

Comment: @edem, большинство за _"или любые другие"_ - это прям очень полезные сведения...

Comment: @Qwertiy это уже неважно, важно то, что предлагалось перед проведением опыта, отклика не нашло.

Comment: @edem, нет, это важно. При убирании причины вполне допускалась возможность её замены на другую. А на какую заменять, этот ответ не отвечает совершенно.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Принятый ответ прошу засчитать как голос от меня (просто это сообщение написал я и не могу голосовать)

Comment: @Qwertiy Принятый ответ прошу засчитать как голос от меня (просто это сообщение написал я и не могу голосовать)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Плохая идея. Некоторые могут подумать, что это принятое решение.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Убрал.

Comment: @Qwertiy в данном ответе всё предельно ясно на какую, на какую и была. Сейчас итог: 17 (с голосом создателя) против 6. Перевес почти в три раза.

Comment: @edem, это неправда.

Comment: @Qwertiy есть опрос. Есть ответ, за который голосуют. Там старая причина. У него (ответа) перевес. Что неправда?

Answer (score 4):

## Причина не нужна

Нет, не возвращать причину учебные задания, а ввести метку или оставить домашки в покое.

Answer (score 3):

## Поменять причину на

> Вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий, например, математику и ввод-вывод. Возможно его стоит разбить на соответствующие атомарные вопросы, но предварительно стоит убедиться, что такие вопросы ещё не задавались, потому что в большинстве случаев вероятность существования таких вопросов достаточно велика.

---

Очевидно, что раз причина использовалась на вопросах, которые закрывать не стоило, возвращать её в той же формулировке абсолютно бессмысленно. Надо подобрать для неё другую, более точную формулировку, чтобы исключить её необоснованное использование.

Этот вариант я предлагал в одном из прошлых [обсуждений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988) - он основан на [соответствующем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988) с рейтингом +23 -2 и призван выделить следующие моменты:

- Большинство домашек из серии "сделай за меня задание целиком" ей неявно покрывается. Никто не задаёт написать функцию поиска минимума в массиве, задуют написать порграмму с заполнением массиваи его обработкой. Если учащийся ничего не дела скопипастил задание, то оно этой причиной почти наверняка покрывается.
- А если всё-таки сделал, и задал вопрос _"как найти минимум в массиве", то это хороший вопрос. Вопросы по азам - это нормально. Их не надо ни закрывать (кроме дубликатов, конечно), ни минусовать.

Comment: Я бы оставил только варианты голосования. Дописывать аргументы против в ответ с вариантом, который вам не нравится - не комильфо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так допиши аргументы за. Лично я их не вижу. Но аргументы должны быть рядом с вариантом в самом ответе.

Comment: Идея заключалась в том, чтобы можно было убедиться в том, что большинство за возвращение причины. Этот ответ по сути соответсвует ответу: "Причина нужна". Просто это переформулированная причина. Теперь тут какой-то хаос: правка вопроса полезная, но правка ответа "Причина нужна" явно намекает "не надо за меня голосовать". Что это еще за перечисление проблем? А то что, если причину уберут проблем будет еще больше?  Я редактирую ответы, делая их снова объективными.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, какой смысл голосовать за "какая-то причина нужна"? Что касается объективности, ответы можно редактировать. Я плюсов в восстановлении старой причины не вижу. Если они есть, то надо чтобы человек, который их видит, взял и перечислил их в ответе. В чём сложность-то? Или плюсов никто не видит, но голосует по принципу "а я хочу"?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica голосование в текущем виде и в подобной формулировке лишь покажет факт голосования. Без аргументации толку особого нету от такого голосования. К тому же, убрали причину не просто так (а по общему решению). Возвращать её теперь в том же виде, в котором она была, смысла нет.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку мое [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10036/195342) получило все же немалое количество плюсов, я хотел бы внаглую добавить на голосование и его, как дополнение:

Добавить к причине закрытия *Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится или опечаткой* еще одну, так что сделать ее следующей:

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, опечаткой или незнанием азов.

Comment: Но для этого же уже есть другая причина.

Comment: Незнание азов не является и не должно являться причиной закрытия вопросов. Это уже обсуждалось.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, тогда сходите на математику (да или даже здесь) и спросите, чему равно 7*8, или хотя бы как его вычислить (правда, это уже даже не совсем азы :)). Ни за что не поверю, что у человека с Интернетом нет возможности найти книгу для чайников и почитать.

Comment: @Harry если так рассуждать, то у нас процентов 30 вопросов нужно удалить как "простые".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica О том и спич - на такие вопросы нужно отвечать в комментариях и удалять, как бесполезные!

Comment: @Harry если их задают из раза в раз, может они, всё же, для кого-то полезные?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ну не лейте так откровенно воду на мою мельницу! :) Опять же - ИМЕННО! Их задают, даже не глядя, есть ли такие вопросы! Поэтому и говорю - на такие вопросы отвечать в комментариях, и удалять - все равно толку от них никакого - новые лентяи ленятся не только книги читать или искать в Интернете ответ, но и искать его в ruSO. А мы ленимся искать дубли, чтоб удалять...

Answer (score 2):

Я хотел бы предложить немного другое видение. 
Если точнее, то оно очень похоже на мнение ***Qwertiy***, лишь за тем исключением, что я бы изменил причину закрытия.

Понимаю, что данный вопрос много раз обсуждался, но учитывая последний комментарий  ***Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica*** решил добавить немного конкретики, так как действительно, хорошо замечено, что просто голосование не сможет полностью отразить мнения людей.

**Тестовые задания**, на мой субъективный взгляд, имеют место быть, за одним исключением. 
Постараюсь объяснить свою позицию(Хотя и предвкушаю множество критики):

Сами по себе тестовые задания - неотъемлемая часть обучения, и, даже длительное время работая с определённым языком программирования, всегда появляются новые обновления, новые методы, новые подходы и так далее. И Порой, многие даже из опытных людей могут почерпнуть для себя оттуда массу полезного. 
Основная проблема, на мой взгляд, - это халатное отношение людей к подобным заданиям. Люди перестали стараться думать самостоятельно и стараться решить задачу. Гораздо проще и быстрее просто поискать решение в интернете. Безусловно в этом есть и часть смысла, ведь таким образом можно найти более удобное, более комфортное и более правильное решение задачи. 
Вот только сама суть тестовых заданий - это научить искать подходы к задаче, а не её решение. Вся проблема в том, что большинство ребят, задающих вопросы по тестовым заданиям - даже не пробовали его решить самостоятельно. Даже не открывали. Да и зачем, если просто можно задать вопрос на `SO` тупо закинув задачу картинкой, даже не заморачиваяться и переписывать её.

Я согласен с ***Qweriy*** ***Victor says Reinstate Monica*** ***Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica*** и многими другими в том, что нельзя решать задачи за других, не давая шанса начать думать самостоятельно. Можно помогать в определённых моментах. И проблемы с частями тестовых заданий не исключение, если человек действительно пытался сделать и приложил свои усилия.

**На мой взгляд решения здесь может быть 2:**
Добавить причину закрытия вопросов

> Отсутствуют попытки самостоятельного решения задачи или попытки разобраться в вопросе.
>  Или же вопрос подразумевает полное решение всей задачи.

---

В этом случае, не думаю, что кто-то будет против тега **тестовые заданий**.
Если человек искренне пытается разобраться в тестовой задаче, но у него искренне не получается - почему бы не помочь такому человеку, подсказать, дать направление, без полного решения задачи за него.

Если же данный подход по мнению большинства изначально ошибочный - то вернуть причину отказа ***Тестовые задания*** и не добавлять подобного тега, так как нельзя делать тестовые задания за людей, не давая им шанса на самостоятельное решение. Тем самым мы не помогаем авторам, а наоборот мешаем. 
 
Люди специально тратят много времени на создание подобных задач и не просто так. Это тоже очень не лёгкий процесс.

***P.S*** Так же поддерживаю идею о разделении вопросов на атомарные части.

Comment: С твоей формулировкой вот это тоже под закрытие https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685411/178988? И твой собственный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1033169/178988? Там же нет попыток решения в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мой можно удалить - он никак не сможет помочь сообществу в дальнейшем. В тот момент мне действительно стоило добавить примеры своих множественных попыток. Но активно я на сайте с 15 декабря, и на момент формулировки вопроса ещё не был знаком со всеми правилами сообщества.

Comment: А смысл от этих попыток? Если ответ пишется за пару минут, то нафига мне в вопросе 10 минут читать пачку попыток, которые не работают? А если не читать, а держать для галочки, то они явно являются лишней информацией.

Comment: @Qwertiy Смысл в попытке самостоятельно разобраться в вопросе, прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: Т. е. для галочки?

Comment: @Qweriy *Для галочки* это грубо сказано... Суть в прикладывании усилий к самостоятельному понимаю вопрос, особенно тестового. А примеры попыток зачастую упрощают возможность дать более быстрый и качественный ответ. Вы не всегда точно знаете, что происходит в проекте спрашивающего. Демонстрация попыток может направить на общее видение картины, вместо задавания дополнительных вопросов автору в комментариях.

Comment: В половине случаев в простых вопросах попытки спрашивающего что-то сделать абсолютно бесполезны.