# Возвращение причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

Ссылки по теме:

- [Нужна ли нам причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/15479)
- [Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9631/15479)
- [Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/15479).
- [Отключение причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9743/15479).

Итоги эксперимента по отключению причины:

- [Небольшое подведение итогов эксперимента по отключению причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10013/15479).

Причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания» снова в строю. Всех поздравляю!

Comment: Да, появилась в списках причин.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica. Ура)

Comment: Что за фигня? Мы ж не так договаривались.

Comment: ерунда какая-то, опять сломали мой stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Grundy все вопросы к голосующим за возвращение причины. Можешь попробовать перезапустить инициативу, может ты аргументы лучше подберёшь.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, _Будем играть в пинг-понг каждые 3 месяца._ :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/of31o.jpg

Answer (score 5):

## Поздравляю все SOобщество с тем, что оно сново очищено от домашек!

Теперь каждое SOобщение с домашкой будет закрыто по правильной причине, как онo того и требует. Огромное спасибо модератору @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica за то, что он вернул причину и повысил качество сообщества. Поведение модератора @Qwertiy мне кажется просто бессмысленным т.к голосование, даже не получившее никакой поддержки (а именно метки важное) и может быть немного испорченное, все равно показало правильное решение.

Спасибо всему SOобществу и всем модераторам за вовремя исправленную ошибку: возвращение причины!

Comment: Твоё голосование некорректно, точнее, [его результат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=53468457#53468457). Ты выдаёшь совершенно бессмысленный вариант _"вернуть или заменить на что угодно"_ за тот, который лично ты считаешь нужным - _"вернуть как было"._ Даже после голосования так ответ исправил, что и послужило последней каплей для блокировки вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я добавил эту строчку("или любые другие, но соответствующие тому, что домашки надо закрывать.") т.к вы сделали из голосования хаос:добавили свой вариант и другие тоже начали. Я пытался этой строчкой покрыть ваш вариант тоже т.к по сути он тоже говорит, что домашки надо закрывать. Потом появился ваш едкий коммент: "большинство за "или любые другие" - это прям очень полезные сведения...". Тогда я решил убрать эту строку...

Comment: ...Тут вы психанули и заблокировали сообщение. В общем я старался сделать культурное голосование и если я ошибся извините. P.S. Этим комментарием вы нарушаете Code of Conduct и показываете свою неуравновешенность, а для модератора ИМХО это плохо.

Comment: Единственное, что можно вынести из того ответа, это то, что большинство за закрытие домашек по специально выделенной для этого причине. О том же, какая именно это должна быть причина, оттуда вывод сделать невозможно. Комментарий подправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy В принципе я с вами абсолютно согласен.Я тогда зря отредактировал. Ваша причина не хуже изначальной.

Comment: @Qwertiy А вообще, какая разница какая причина, если домашки будут закрывать по специальной для этого причине?

Comment: Разница в том, что текущую версию причины не очень хорошо понимают и используют для закрытия того, что закрывать не надо. А ещё по её использованию периодически задают вопросы на мете. Надо сделать однозначную причину, которая будет чётко разграничивать онтопик и офтопик, которая будет понятна людям и которой будут пользоваться по делу. Не обязательно мою, но какую-то другую. Причину убрали не просто так, а потому что с ней били сложности. Возвращать её обратно - это шаг назад. Надо устраивать голосование за новую формулировку с пояснениями, на что каждая из них направлена.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ваша причина так сформулирована, что по ней можно закрывать и другие вопросы.

Comment: Хорошие или плохие? Если хорошие, то значит надо формулировать по-другому. Потому и надо нормальное голосование именно по причинам.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вообще ваша тревога правильней. Вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082976/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8) может и не учебное задание, но закрыть его надо. Ваша причина как раз подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно голосование по данному вопросу. Обязательно с меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5). И обязательно с проработкой ответов в [мета-чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22474/). Я, конечно, за введение, но глас всего заинтересованного народа надо бы услышать вполне. А то как-то сумбурно этот процесс прошел, IMHO.

Comment: "Глас" уже [возопил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10070/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f?cb=1) вполне. ...

Comment: ...Голосование тоже уже [провели](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10084/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Уже все ясно. Что не так?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica без метки "важное" возопил. Хотя, возможно, все заинтересованные там и проголосовали. Но, кстати, несогласные всегда могут создать тему на мете, так что, думаю, Qwertiy сможет убедиться в поддержке данного решения

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, [всё не так](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=53468457#53468457).

Answer (score -1):

Я прекращаю отвечать на сайте пока эта причина не будет переформулирована.

Comment: А чего так критично? В идеале я тоже за изменение формулировки. Но если все решили вернуть старую формулировку - это лучше, чем ничего. Вы разве модераторами не коллегиально решаете подобные вопросы?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, никто ничего не решал. Кучу раз переписанный ответ с голосами непонятно за какую версию - это не решение. Suvitruf обещал задать вопрос о том, что делать с причиной с нормальными вариантами ответа на него. Вместо этого причину просто взяли и вернули. Без всякого нормального обсуждения. Столько усилий чтобы её снести впустую.

Comment: @Qweriy, Я понимаю Ваше негодование, но разве нельзя ввести голосование на текущем этапе? Ведь в теории это не несёт критичного вреда. Все проголосуют, и, если что, Вы же сможете поменять, верно? В общем я за мирное урегулирование вопроса.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, не вижу никаких попыток сделать нормальное голосование.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, не нужно голосование - бесполезную причину нужно просто убрать модераторам и все

Comment: @Grundy сообщество решило убрать, потом сообщество решило вернуть. Будем играть в пинг-понг каждые 3 месяца.

Comment: @Denis640Kb несёт.

Comment: А что конкретно с формулировкой не так?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, тот момент, когда нужен [tag:модераторский-произвол] :-D

Comment: @Grundy ещё не вечер (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Подскажите, какой вред это может принести? Может я что-то упустил. Большинство людей проголосовало за возвращение причины закрытия. И моё мнение тоже в том числе. И я благодарен Вам за то, что Вы внесли такую инициативу. Но Qwertiy тоже верно заметил, что в посте постоянно меняли текст и причины в голосах "ЗА". Я веду к тому, что причину надо точно оставить, но можно подобрать более удобную формулировку, которая будет отображать целостное мнение. Сейчас причина есть и это хорошо. В чём может быть вред запуска голосования за формулировку?

Comment: @Denis640Kb я про вред возврата причины в текущем виде.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, но это не помешало тебе её вернуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy "не вижу никаких попыток сделать нормальное голосование" - а если бы оно было, и причину вернули бы без изменений, то вы бы поступили точно так же?

Comment: @Miron, вероятно нет. Но его не было.

Comment: @Miron тема ещё не закрыта. В текущем виде причина закрытия работает плохо. Как минимум, нужно изменить текст.

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему [это голосование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10084/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) не считается? Если не считать того, что его закрыли, за пару дней и не все активные участники смогли проголосовать.

Comment: @RTK, потому что голоса отданы за непонятно какую формулировку ответа. Потому вопрос и был закрыт. [Вот тут подробнее расписано](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=53468457#53468457).

Comment: Все, что это дало - для меня - это то, что  сейчас, вместо чтоб писать руками текст, что бла-бла-бла - просто ткнул в эту кнопочку. Но голосовал бы я за закрытие точно так же. Стоит это того, чтоб объявлять забастовку?... тогда уж лучше было бы уйти из модераторов, чем из отвечающих - это было бы круче :)

Comment: @Harry, а я не считаю правильным уходить из модераторов.

Comment: @Qwertiy *"к рассвету, однако, дело уладилось, — порешили отказаться от диких яблок и слив. Раньше мы чувствовали себя не совсем ловко, но теперь все устроилось отлично. Я остался очень доволен тем, как это удачно вышло, потому что дикие яблоки и всегда-то бывают не особенно вкусны, а тут они еще не успели созреть."* Марк Твен, "Приключения Гекльберри Финна" :)

Comment: А чего так категорично? Вы же модератор, у вас кроме как забастовкой нет возможности что то решить или как то договориться? Почему у одного модератора есть возможность и отключить причину и вернуть ее обратно, а другому надо бастовать чтобы чего то добиться? "- Я, однажды, чтобы вернуть девушку, в метро голый проехался. - А как это помогло? - Никак, но было весело" - фильм "Управление гневом"

Comment: Почитал на счет последнего голосования. Частично согласен с Qwertiy на счет того, что варианты были подобраны неудачно. Как я уже писал "вернуть как было и думать над решением, которое всех удовлетворит - это хорошо". Раз вопрос остается актуальным, то что мешает сейчас провести голосование, где каждый сможет написать свой вариант?

Comment: @RTK, вероятно это кто-то должен сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy да сделаю на выходных, сделаю. У меня жесть на работе сейчас, совсем времени нет подумать основательно над этим.