# Правила при отправке тревог

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Возможно, я чего-то не допонимаю или правила поменялись.

Я активный участник на конкретном теге без особых претензий на звания хочу знать, почему кто-то, кто вообще мимо крокодил (1 бал репутации), может отменить мои тревоги, причем с убогими формулировками, типа, тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства?

Адекватность данных пользователей для меня под сомнением, как и сама система тревог, которая допускает их участие.

Какого лешего, простите? В тревогах есть специальный пункт, чтобы позвать модератора, я его вообще никогда не нажимаю.

В остальном я, вроде не глуп, могу понять, когда пользователь заказывает музыку, а когда ищет решение самостоятельно.

- Одному мне кажется, что система тревог не работает как надо?
- А как должна работать система тревог? Я ожидаю, что это система отбраковки сообщений первой очереди, т.е. должны отсеиваться спам, вопросы не по теме и заказы. Но на деле я получаю 25% отклоненных тревог с просьбой почитать правила от условных участников без какой-либо репутации.
- Что мне делать, чтобы не расстраиваться по этим пустякам? [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082535/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-google-spreadsheets). Пользователь в своем проекте на связь не выходит. Замечания не принимает. Явно ждет решения. По его активности видно, что он смотрит в документ. Какую тревогу отправить, чтобы опять какой-нибудь дух ее не отклонил?

Я заметил, что не стало пункта в тревогах, в котором четко говорилось, что нельзя задавать задания. Надеюсь, что я просто проморгал его. Или действительно удалили?

### Обновление 2020-02-15

Я реально неправильно понимал список тревог. Все пользователи, на которых можно перейти из тревоги, это обычные пользователи, например, те, кто задали вопрос.

Из комментариев к сообщению, до меня дошло, как это работает. Почитал еще немного мету про тревоги, пересмотрел отношение к вопросам, и думаю, что мне стоит меньше огорчаться по пустякам. Так сказать, чуть больше пофигизма.

Постараюсь делать меньше тревог и побольше забивать.

Comment: Да, этот пункт про домашние задания убирали на период эксперимента, а потом [возвращали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10100/213987).

Comment: `кто-то, кто вообще мимо крокодил (1 бал репутации)` - если вы про [Дух Сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/Дух-сообщества) - то это вообще не человек а бот.

Comment: _Что мне делать, чтобы не расстраиваться по этим пустякам?_ - ничего, просто не брать в голову. У вас пока нет кнопки [закрыть] (появится >=3к). Вы попадаете в меню по голосованию за закрытие вопроса через соответствующий выбор в меню тревог, а участники с большей репутацией через кнопку [закрыть]. То есть, что вы делаете, это не совсем трвога, а полу-тревога. Когда голосование по закрытию закончится, в зависимости от его результата, Дух (т.е. бот) либо увеличит счётчик полезных тревог, либо отклонит тревогу. Модераторы вам напишут, если подряд таких авто-отклонеённых тревог будет много.

Comment: @insolor, не, я именно про пользователей.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо. Подтяну репутацию.

Comment: Я неправильно использовал слово "Дух". Имелось ввиду "новичок", "новобранец".

Comment: @contributorpw, нужны конкретные примеры. Насколько я знаю, не-модераторы не могут отменять чужие тревоги, если это действительно тревоги, а не голоса за закрытие, например.

Comment: @insolor, голоса за закрытия тоже не могут :)

Comment: Ребята, все правильно говорите. Спасибо большое. Обновил топик немного.

Comment: _Все пользователи, на которых можно перейти из тревоги, это обычные пользователи_ - как можно понять эту фразу? На каких пользователей вы переходите из тревоги?